# chained ifelse() statements, is it possible to indicate if several statements are true at the same time?

Tags: r

In the following example the newvar is 1 because "a" is always smaller than 4. At the same time the second statement is true as well but since the first is already true the newvar remains 1. Is it somehow possible to easily indicate that for some observations, both statements are true? or like an error that indicates that both are true?

```
test <- data.frame(a=c(1,2,3), b=c(3,4,5) )

test <- test %>% 
  mutate(newvar = 
           ifelse(a<4,1,
                  ifelse(b>3,0,NA))
    
  )
```

The original example is a bit more complex and looks like this. I just want to make sure that the ifelse statements do not contradict each other.

```
Indicator <- Indicator %>%
  mutate(severity_scale1 =
           ifelse(no_shelter_and_sleep_open == 1, "4+",
                  ifelse(inadequate_shelter == 1 &
                    (partial_complete_shelter_damage_Indicator1 == 1 |
                      no_secure_tenure_shelter_Indicator2 == 1 |
                      host_displaced_people_Indicator3 == 1), "4",
                    ifelse(inadequate_shelter == 1 &
                             (partial_complete_shelter_damage_Indicator1 == 0 &
                                no_secure_tenure_shelter_Indicator2 == 0 &
                                host_displaced_people_Indicator3 == 0), "3", NA
                           )
                    )
                  )
           )
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `case_when` to test for multiple conditions and start with the condition where both of them are true. Something like this :

```
library(dplyr)

test %>% 
  mutate(newvar = case_when(a < 4 & b > 3 ~ 'both are true', 
                            a < 4 ~ '1', 
                            b > 3  ~ '0'))
#  a b        newvar
#1 1 3             1
#2 2 4 both are true
#3 3 5 both are true
```

Remember the order of condition is important. Here, `a < 4 & b > 3` is tested first and if that is true it doesn't check the next 2 conditions.

Comment: thank you for your answer. but then I need to manually code the first option. since I have several ifelse() statements (chain of ifelse() statements) this would be very complicated and confusing

Comment: Not sure what do you mean by that. Can you update your post to include what you actually want to do? Why using this answer would be complicated?

Comment: I was thinking about case_when function which makes the coding at least more readable. maybe somehow I could randomly arrange the order of the case_when conditions and check in the end if the output is the same. if yes, the order doesnt seem to play a role...

Comment: The logic in both ifelse and case_when is the same. It executes those lines first whose conditions are mentioned first. So while writing these statements you have to start with the narrowest condition first and then go to broader ones. See how the output changes for this example based on the order of the condition. `inds <- 1:15;
case_when(inds %% 5 == 0 ~ 1, inds %% 3 == 0 ~ 2, inds %% 5 == 0 & inds %% 3 == 0 ~ 3` vs `case_when(inds %% 5 == 0 & inds %% 3 == 0 ~ 3, inds %% 5 == 0 ~ 1, inds %% 3 == 0 ~ 2)`